# Getting information back from a process with a multiprocessing Queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am trying to play around with multiprocessing and I would like to communicate between Python's main thread and a subprocess with a Queue. Here is a quick test code I wrote that should get periodically some results generated by the subprocess:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

def calculate(queue):  
    n = 0
    while n < 10:   
        n += 1
        queue.put(n)
        time.sleep(1)
    queue.put(0)

def queue_getter(queue):
    executing = True
    while executing:     
        while queue.qsize():
            n = queue.get()
            print(n)
            if n == 0:
                executing = False
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print('done')

queue = Queue()
p = Process(target=calculate, args=(queue,))
p.start()
queue_getter(queue)
p.join()
print('DONE')
```

This program just hangs forever, while replacing `Process` with `threading.Thread` gives the expected result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
0
done
DONE
```

How to make Process behave the same way as Thread in this situation?

Comment: I think you create a race condition with the unnecessary `while queue.qsize():` If the getter arrives there before the first item has been put in the queue, the getter will exit.

Comment: Calling *qsize()* is unnecessary. Just call *get()* (blocking). Also consider using Manager and ProcessPoolExecutor for a simplified and more robust approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program works fine on POSIX (UNIX-like) systems.

However, for it to work properly on ms-windows and macOS, you will need to put the program itself inside a main block, so the file can be imported without side effects.

This is due to the way `multiprocessing` has to work on ms-windows and macOS. Read the [programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) for multiprocessing.

Modify your code like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time


def calculate(queue):
    n = 0
    while n < 10:
        n += 1
        queue.put(n)
        time.sleep(1)
    queue.put(0)


def queue_getter(queue):
    executing = True
    while executing:
        while queue.qsize():
            n = queue.get()
            print(n)
            if n == 0:
                executing = False
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print("done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = Queue()
    p = Process(target=calculate, args=(queue,))
    p.start()
    queue_getter(queue)
    p.join()
    print("DONE")
```

Comment: This is it, thank you! I must say that when I initially tried this modification, it did not work, but it turns out it was because I was running the code in a Jupyter Notebook. But it actually executes fine in a .py file. When I try to execute my initial code from a .py file, I get an explicit error mentioning exactly what you explain. However in Jupyter Lab it just hangs and prints no error message.

Comment: It has come up on stackoverflow often enough to say that `multiprocessing` should probably *not* be used in a Jupyter notebook. And when writing programs, you should *always* run them with Python directly, not through an IDE or  Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified and more robust approach which is (almost) functionally identical to the OP's original except that is does not print the zero:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time

def calculate(q):
    for n in range(1, 11):
        q.put(n)
        time.sleep(1)
    q.put(0)

def queue_getter(q):
    while (n := q.get()):
        print(n)

def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        q = manager.Queue()
        with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.submit(calculate, q)
            queue_getter(q)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Very concise! Note that `n := q.get()` requires Python 3.8 or newer.

Comment: This is an elegant solution, thank you! Similarly to Roland Smith's solution, it does not work from a Jupyter notebook but is ok from a .py file.